# Programatically populating a textbox within a popup when the popup displays

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api

The Facebook Send button for example (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/send/) displays a popup with a To: field. Is it possible to programatically populate that To: field with a name after it popups?

Comment: This would have to happen through the Facebook api. You can't access their popup through your page, it only exists through the connection you have with them.

Comment: Can I not use the jquery live feature to do this?

Comment: What you can try is, use the Firebug element selector feature to select to To: textbox in the popup, and see if it gives you the field, and then try and set it using Jquery in .live() and see if that works.

Comment: It will NOT let you modify something in a window or iframe that's not on the same domain, I tried that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The facebook api doesn't allow you to pass in a default value for the To: field.  As a security measure, cross-site scripting is not allowed.

You can [read more about cross-site scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) and why it's not allowed here.